# SPQuery on null lookupfield

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, xml, spquery

I have a contact list with a company lookup field and I need to retrieve those without any company associated

so I was thinking can I put it like this:

```
<Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Company" />
          <Value Type="Lookup"></Value> //or should I put null since it's a lookup field??
        </Eq>
      </Where>
    </Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want items with no lookup value you could use:

```
<IsNull><FieldRef Name='Company'/></IsNull>
```

Comment: hey I just wanted to ask if we want to check this field lookup value in XSL format this wont work `<xsl:when test="Company !=null">
        <xsl:value-of select="Company" />
    </xsl:when>` do you have any idea?

Comment: Just if anyone esle is asking I found it and it's like that `<xsl:when test="Company !=''"> <xsl:value-of select="Company" /> </xsl:when>`

Comment: That's nice. You should just ask a new question next time, so other people can find it :)